# React - Unknown prop `page_id` on <div> tag. Remove this prop from the element

Tags: facebook, reactjs, facebook-customer-chat

I'm integrating Facebook's [Customer Chat Plugin](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/discovery/customer-chat-plugin#) to my website. In the instructions it says:

```
include a div with the following attributes in your HTML:
<div class="fb-customerchat"
 page_id="<PAGE_ID>"
 ref="<OPTIONAL_WEBHOOK_PARAM>">
</div>
```

When I did so (this is the React version) :

```
<div className="fb-customerchat"
 page_id="<PAGE_ID>"
 ref="<OPTIONAL_WEBHOOK_PARAM>">
</div>
```

... I got this error from React: `Warning: Unknown prop`page_id`on <div> tag. Remove this prop from the element. For details, see https://reactjs.org/warnings/unknown-prop.html`, and the customer chat plugin isn't shown at all (I can still find the HTML elements in the DOM tree).
I did some searching and it seems like React doesn't recognize the custom `page_id` attribute. I tried changing it to `data-page_id` but it doesn't help.
Have anyone encountered the same problem and how did you resolve it ?

Comment: have you included Facebook JavaScript SDK on the page?

Comment: @xSkrappy Yes I have, I checked in the browser console, the `FB` global variable is available

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the Customer Chat Plugin needs an HTML element inserted into the DOM with the parameters specified. With React, you're never passing in raw HTML, hence the error message. To resolve this, you can do either:
- insert the `.fb-customerchat` div directly to your HTML or
- use this package: https://github.com/Yoctol/react-messenger-customer-chat which is a workaround for React

Answer (score 0):

https://react-cn.github.io/react/docs/tags-and-attributes.html

Looks like page id is not supported. Try using `classID` or just `id`

Comment: But in the docs (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/discovery/customer-chat-plugin#) it mentioned using exactly page_id :( This value will be read by the Facebook JS SDK then